# Safe Login using Sessions & Cookies

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I currently use sessions to log users into my site. Now, I want to add cookies into the mix so people can visit the site days later and not have to log in again.

I don't want to store passwords in cookies, or encrypt anything - so my solution is to store the username in the cookie, and create another cookie with a sort of login hash (specific to each login of each user). And then, at the top of each page, check for the cookie and a login session. If the cookie is present but the session isn't, find the username and log the user in.

So, this would happen after they log in successfully (`$row['username']` is the username they typed in):

```
$_SESSION['username']=$row[username];
$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['id'];
$loginhash = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 32);
$number_of_days = 14;
$date_of_expiry = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * $number_of_days ;
setcookie( "userlogin", $row['username'], $date_of_expiry, "/" ) ;
setcookie( "loginhash", $loginhash, $date_of_expiry, "/" ) ;

$today=date("Y-m-d");

mysql_query("update members set last_login='$today',loginhash='$loginhash' where id='$row[id]' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

And then at the top of each page, do something like:

```
if($_COOKIE['userlogin'] && !isset($_SESSION[user_id])){
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['userlogin']);
    $loginhash=mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['loginhash']);
    $result=mysql_query("select * from members where (username='$username' || email='$username') && loginhash='$loginhash' ") or die (mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['username']=$row[username];
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['id'];
}
```

And then, of course, unset the cookie when user manually logs out.

My question is, is this a safe thing to do (apart from the danger of someone else using the user's computer)? The random hash is generated for every login so someone couldn't just create a cookie with somebody's username and log in as that person.

The login script is on HTTPS so there's no danger on that side.

Comment: I would store the username and a hash specific to the username to take care of any hash collisions. Other than that it seems pretty standard.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security, and should be transferred to [Security.SE].

Comment: You've already identified the biggest issue (someone else using the computer). To ensure that the cookie and session remained in sync you would need to update the cookie on every fetch to the session variable.

Comment: Depends on your definition of safe. There is always the ability to copy cookies from one computer to another.

Comment: @Robadob Is there really danger of that, with a 32-character random string? The odds of a collision are somewhere around 60^32, correct?

Comment: @Anigel I mean "safe" as in "there's nothing more I can do":)

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm referring to PHP server-side security, which is basically a programming question. I only mentioned the other kind of security as a side note.

Comment: It seems pretty safe to me. It will be pretty hard to brute-force into someone's account. For security reasons, I would disable such a feature for accounts with additional rights. Furthermore test if a user can get any other information from this mechanic by forging specific cookies or log into an account that hasn't this feature enabled by using an empty hash (or the standard value).

Comment: @jovan If I understand 'str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")' correctly there are 61!-29! as no characters are repeated. Usually people would produce a sha512 hash of the current timestamp appended to the username and a salt (or similar).
It's not so much an issue of it's really unlikely to happen, it's more implementing an additional check of user is so simple compared to the cost of if hashes did collide and someone gained access to anothers account in some commercial system.

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't consider that the characters don't repeat. Thanks.

Comment: also: [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions have been deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, this is not secure!

I can see two major issues with the way you're doing this:

1. The reason we don't store passwords in the database is so that in the event of a database compromise, an attacker can't gain access to the accounts on our server... but this is exactly what you're doing with your `loginhash`. **If I compromise your database, I can log in as any user with an active cookie for the next 14 days** just by creating a cookie with the `username` and the `loginhash` from the database.

   You can rectify this by generating your random key, storing that in a cookie, then running it through a hashing function like `bcrypt` and storing the digest in your database. This way, even with a full dump of your database, a user cannot simply log into your site as any other user. You will, of course, have to change the comparison operator so that it compares the digest instead of the raw.
2. **The `str_shuffle` function is not cryptographically secure.** It uses `rand` internally which is fairly predictable and would make this hash a lot easier attack vector than your passwords. Instead, use the random entropy on your OS (URANDOM refers to Unblocking Random, it's not as secure as RANDOM but as your system will be doing a lot of processing -- and thus generating entropy -- it will suffice) like this:

Adapted from [this password reset class](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/StoPasswordReset.html):

```
function generateRandomBase64String($length = 32)
{
  if (!defined('MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM')) die('The MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM source is required (PHP 5.3).');
  $binaryLength = (int)($length * 3 / 4 + 1);
  $randomBinaryString = mcrypt_create_iv($binaryLength, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
  $randomBase64String = base64_encode($randomBinaryString);
  return substr($randomBase64String, 0, $length);
}
```

### Now, we need to make cookie jacking much more difficult

[This article](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice) explains how Drupal handles login tokens, storing a `username`, `loginhash` and `series_id` together every time a user logs in with credentials instead of using a cookie. The `loginhash` and `series_id` can be generated using the aforementioned random function.

When a user logs in, the database is checked. If the `username`, `loginhash` and `series_id` are all present, the user is logged in and a **new cookie** is generated with the same `username` and `series_id` but a new `loginhash`. This means that each cookie can only be used once.

Additionally, users logged in this way are not able to do any compromising functions like requesting a password reset, withdrawing funds and viewing sensitive information without doing a 'proper' password login. This is to secure users who have has their cookie jacked.

If a login is detected where the `series_id` is present but the `loginhash` does not match, we wipe all valid cookies for this user and leave him a strongly worded message indicating that an invalid cookie was used to access his account.

### On a side note re `mysql_*` functions

This seems like new code and not yet deployed. If it's not too late to turn back, consider switching your database driver to `mysqli` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) which maintains a very similar procedural style to `mysql` but allows you to use bound parameters and other modern functions to improve data security.

Comment: It's way too late for mysqli. As for the other points, I understand and I will use your advice. Thanks.

Comment: @jovan As someone who maintains a lot of legacy code, I understand that position entirely. `mysql_*` is safe when used correctly. I have added a section on how to deal with cookie jacking attacks.

Comment: Yup, this is part of a website that's been online for a while, and the whole thing is done with mysql so migrating at this point would be a huge task.

Comment: A thought just came to me - what about AJAX? Right now if a user leaves the site open and his session expires, then tries to make an AJAX request, it tells him he has to log in again. Do you think adding the same check ($_COOKIE && !$_SESSION) to each PHP file that AJAX calls is the way to go?

Comment: @jovan Yes as long as the AJAX function wouldn't compromise the account if it was a stolen cookie. I suggest fine-tuning which actions are allowed with a cookie login and which ones aren't (password change, account details change, anything to do with money etc.)

Comment: @jovan The problem is that stealing cookies is [relatively uncomplicated](http://atenlabs.com/blog/how-to-steal-facebook-authentication-cookies/), so you should always assume cookies can get stolen.

Comment: I see. Well, it's an online game so nothing of any spectacular importance could happen (no payment details or anything are saved on the site) but I agree it's a good idea to ask for the password again if they try to change account details etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are some points you should improve:

1. First the login token would better be generated with the operating-systems random source (URANDOM). Your code will use each character only once, and the shuffle function is probably based on the current time (random number). Knowing the approximate login time, will therefore narrow down the possible combinations badly.
2. The token should not be stored plaintext in the database, instead you should store only a hash of it in the database. If somebody can read your database (SQL-injection), he can still not use the code.
3. The function `setcookie()` has two parameters `$secure` and `$httponly`, you should set both to true. Otherwise the browser can be tricked to send the token unencrypted to an HTTP page (it will even be sent to image requests).